# Bootstrap 3 Carousel: Replace indicators with text

Tags: text, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am trying to replace the indicators on a bootstrap carousel with text, almost like a navigation of sorts but have not successfully discovered how to do this even after hours of searching. I have found a lot of css options for customizing the indicators, but not a method for replacing them with text entirely. The text will be an identifying title for the carousel "slide". Naturally the code is

```
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>
```

I would like to say I've tried a lot, but everything has been a shot in the dark and I knew it was going the wrong direction to begin with. I appreciate help in advance figuring this out.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it:

HTML

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">text1</li>
   <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1">text2</li>
   <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2">text3</li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-indicators li{
    text-indent:0;
    width:200px;
    height: 40px;
    border:none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```